# the reference to nuget packages are not being recognized on server

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

So, I have 2 nuget packages that im using on my website... System.JSON, and NewtonSoft.JSON. I've recently moved my web app from my local machine to a new staging environment. When i visit this page on the new staging environment i receive the error **The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System**. So i removed that using statement and the associated code, I receive the same error for NewtonSoft.JSON (Another nuget package). I also remove that using statement as well as the code using it, and everything works fine.

I can add a nuget package for EntityFramework, and plop the using statement in the code for that, and I now receive an error for entity framework.

**It seems any nuget packages i've added will work fine only on my local machine, but when I try to access as a website, i receive the error**. This error is only happening when i visit the webpage containing these nugets.

I've even went as far as installing visual studio on the staging server, rebuilding/cleaning the solution and i still get the same error stating the namespaces for my nugets do not exist. I've checked the bin folder, the dll's are clearly there.

Any help on direction on this would be a god send, Thanks.

Comment: How are you deploying this artifact? As a .zip file? How are you building it? Help us out with your steps.

Comment: How is the website deployed? Are the corresponding DLL files included in the bin folder of your website?

Comment: I've just built this as a C# ASP.NET web application on my local machine, and ive copied this code over to a new server, set the binding to point to my code. I can visit pages on the site that dont use the nuget packages, but when I go to a page that does i have issues where non of my nugets are found

Comment: Yes, the files are located in the bin

Comment: So you shouldn't be copying code, you should be copying artifacts. One way to make sure you're doing this with Visual Studio is to right-click the project and click "Publish..." then specify a location. The outputs in that location will match the artifacts of your built project.

Comment: I've actually tried this with no luck. I published the site to my local file system. Move the published code to staging and still nuget packages are not recognized.